# Kong / Istio Service Mesh How to enable https?

Tags: istio, kong

I am using Kong as an API Gateway and Istio as a service mesh. I can't seem to find any documentation to enable `https` on my user facing microservice? What is the recommended approach to enable `https` with Kong? I have also enabled mtls on Istio but that is only inside of the cluster.

I would love to enable https on my user facing Microservice so that a user just has to go to `https://myawesome-service.org`. Please advise.

Comment: as a side note, istio can act as api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this similar problem](https://discuss.konghq.com/t/kong-ingress-controller-and-istio-service-mesh-with-strict-mtls/8386). There you will find an example configuration that needed to be tweaked. For your situation very useful could be [Peer Authentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/peer_authentication/):

> PeerAuthentication defines how traffic will be tunneled (or not) to the sidecar.

You could find there completely guide how to set it up properly.

See also [this topic](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/03/18/kong-ingress-controller-and-istio-service-mesh/).